# Deploy keras (with theano backend) on a LAMP (python) stack with flask?

Tags: apache, webserver, lamp, theano, keras

I am trying to deploy a Flask web app with keras and theano on compute engine. 
When I `import keras` 
and run sudo service apache2 restart, the server goes into a loop ("waiting for IP address"). 
The error.log gives the following error

```
[:error] [pid 1588:tid 140666780755712] Using Theano backend.
```

I am on ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got keras working on compute engine. To import heavy libraries we need to set certain parameters in `.conf` file.

Add the following code to your `/etc/apache2/sites-enables/yourapp.conf` file:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess yourapp user=you group=somegroup processes=1 threads=5
<Directory /home/directory/to/webserver/html/appdir/app.wsgi>
    WSGIProcessGroup yourapp
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Refer this link for details - http://cmry.github.io/notes/bottle